# Try without Except

Tags: try-catch, except

Is it possible to use try without except? Sometimes it doesn't matter if some iterations crash, but using conditions (maybe more than one) looks weirdly

```
# in my dreams:

for i in lines:
    try:
        print(i[3])
```

Comment: If you just want to do nothing in the error case, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress

Answer (score 0):

Try needs an `except` or `finally` block following it. If you want to leave it empty, try this

```
try:
    /*Your code here*/
except:
    pass
```

EDIT: If you're confident that your block won't raise an exception, you could just remove the try block altogether

```
for i in lines:
    print(i[3])
```